# Cycling a variable around a power of two range

Tags: c++, c, idioms

What construct is preferable, and why?

A:

```
if(i < 1023)
   ++i;
else
   i = 0;
```

B:

```
++i;
if(i == 1024)
  i = 0;
```

C:

```
i = (i + 1) & 1023;
```

or other?

I like alternative C because it is small and has no branch (thus, no pipeline break), but it performs an AND operation that is useful only in 1 of each 1024 times...

Comment: If speed is more important than readability, I'd go with **C**. The AND is no more expensive than the comparison that the other choices do each time, let alone the cost of the branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would choose option **C** every time.  It might be less immediately obvious, but the idiom is clear enough to anybody with coding experience, and it saves you that conditional branch.  On modern (i.e. anything easily in the past 10 years) superscalar processors, the bottleneck is memory and/or branch prediction; arithmetic ops like the binary AND are, to a good approximation, free.

Answer (score 0):

Running them in a 100k for loop gives me these results:
A: 10.439 sec
B:  9.845 sec
C:  9.482 sec
Personally I would use A because I'm used to that kind of notation and it keeps it clear. If speed is an issue, C seems to be the best out of these three.

Comment: what compiler optimization parameters?

Comment: @thang None, I think, I use code::blocks with mingw. No optimization flags are set.

Comment: @Kevin: No optimization means your measurement is meaningless -- you're mostly measuring the foibles of the compiler's instruction selector.